# How to fix "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'"?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

My aim is streaming object detection video from Raspberry Pi camera to UDP. I am doing that on Nvidia Jetson Nano(Ubuntu 18.04). I am using gstreamer to capture video. I have to encode video with h264. Pixel Format of camera is 'RG10'. I tried different pipeline to capture video but nothing is changed. I think, problem is capturing video. I could not figure out. I am newbies. So I need help.

Here is code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages')
import cv2 as cv2

from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','labelmap.pbtxt')
NUM_CLASSES = 1

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

writer = cv2.VideoWriter(" appsrc name=appsrc_element block=true ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! identity check-imperfect-timestamp=true ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! video/x-h264,profile=\"high-4:4:4\ ! rtph264pay  ! udpsink host= 192.168.1.49 port=5000 ",cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER,0, 20, (320,240), True) # Write frames here after processing


video = cv2.VideoCapture('nvarguscamerasrc ! image/jpg,width=1280,height=720,type=video,framerate=30/1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! appsink ', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
ret = video.set(3,1280)
ret = video.set(4,720)

while(True):


    ret, frame = video.read()   
    frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)


    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.85)

    w_size = cv2.getWindowImageRect('frame')

    print(w_size)
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(int(int(w_size[2])*0.25) ,int(int(w_size[3])*0.10)),(int(int(w_size[2])*0.75),int(int(w_size[3])*0.90)),(0,255,0),3)

    writer.write(frame) 


    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is output error :

```
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/berfu/.virtualenvs/deep_learning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/berfu/.virtualenvs/deep_learning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/berfu/.virtualenvs/deep_learning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/berfu/.virtualenvs/deep_learning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/berfu/.virtualenvs/deep_learning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
2019-09-07 02:26:33.800624: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:98] Failed to find bogomips in /proc/cpuinfo; cannot determine CPU frequency
2019-09-07 02:26:33.804717: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:161] XLA service 0x2816fdf0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-09-07 02:26:33.805320: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-09-07 02:26:33.895575: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:965] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-07 02:26:33.895923: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:161] XLA service 0x24aca990 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-09-07 02:26:33.895984: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA Tegra X1, Compute Capability 5.3
2019-09-07 02:26:33.896452: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: NVIDIA Tegra X1 major: 5 minor: 3 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.9216
pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0
totalMemory: 3.86GiB freeMemory: 272.39MiB
2019-09-07 02:26:33.896515: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-09-07 02:26:35.073590: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-09-07 02:26:35.073769: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 
2019-09-07 02:26:35.073809: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N 
2019-09-07 02:26:35.074121: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 42 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA Tegra X1, pci bus id: 0000:00:00.0, compute capability: 5.3)
GST_ARGUS: Creating output stream
CONSUMER: Waiting until producer is connected...
GST_ARGUS: Available Sensor modes :
GST_ARGUS: 3280 x 2464 FR = 21.000000 fps Duration = 47619048 ; Analog Gain range min 1.000000, max 10.625000; Exposure Range min 13000, max 683709000;

GST_ARGUS: 3280 x 1848 FR = 28.000001 fps Duration = 35714284 ; Analog Gain range min 1.000000, max 10.625000; Exposure Range min 13000, max 683709000;

GST_ARGUS: 1920 x 1080 FR = 29.999999 fps Duration = 33333334 ; Analog Gain range min 1.000000, max 10.625000; Exposure Range min 13000, max 683709000;

GST_ARGUS: 1280 x 720 FR = 59.999999 fps Duration = 16666667 ; Analog Gain range min 1.000000, max 10.625000; Exposure Range min 13000, max 683709000;

GST_ARGUS: 1280 x 720 FR = 120.000005 fps Duration = 8333333 ; Analog Gain range min 1.000000, max 10.625000; Exposure Range min 13000, max 683709000;

GST_ARGUS: Running with following settings:
   Camera index = 0 
   Camera mode  = 2 
   Output Stream W = 1920 H = 1080 
   seconds to Run    = 0 
   Frame Rate = 29.999999 
GST_ARGUS: PowerService: requested_clock_Hz=13608000
GST_ARGUS: Setup Complete, Starting captures for 0 seconds
GST_ARGUS: Starting repeat capture requests.
CONSUMER: Producer has connected; continuing.
GST_ARGUS: Cleaning up
GST_ARGUS: 
PowerServiceHwVic::cleanupResources
CONSUMER: Done Success
GST_ARGUS: Done Success
<class 'NoneType'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webcam.py", line 68, in <module>
    feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})
  File "/home/berfu/.virtualenvs/deep_learning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/berfu/.virtualenvs/deep_learning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1121, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "/home/berfu/.virtualenvs/deep_learning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Thank you, for your help

Answer (score 0):

The values in `feed_dict` have to be convertible to a numpy array - it looks like `frame_expanded` may contain `None`. Try printing the `feed_dict` values to see if it contains valid data.

Comment: I could not print ```feed_dict``` but ```frame``` is ```None``

Comment: That would explain it - `video.read()` returned `None` because it couldn't capture the frame. ("If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer.")